# How to use custom permalink for specific category in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My current permalink is set to /%postname%/.

I want to keep this. but I want to use custom permalink for a specific cateogory "blog".

Can anyone help me, how to achieve this without using plugins?

Answer (score -2):

I found this solution: "Add Custom Taxonomy Tags to Your WordPress Permalinks". It might help you as well. See here: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks