# Getting WordPress to automatically show category permalink for only specific categories

Tags: wordpress

I have searched, [here is the closes result.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933295/how-to-use-custom-permalink-for-specific-category-in-wordpress-post)

I am building a new wordpress site. I want most posts to have no category in the URL, simply www.site.com/title. However I do want the blog posts to be separate, so I'd like www.site.com/blog/title. I'd also like the option to add more like that in the future, for only specific categories, not the entire site.

There are many questions similar to this here on stackoverflow but most have 0 replies. Any advice would be great. I've even tried [Advanced Permalinks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-permalinks/) without any luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do that by Setting > Permalinks and add to Common Setting > Custom Structure the value `/blog/%postname%/`. There you will get the blog post accessible from www.site.com/blog/title.

I cannot understand the first question. By:

> I want most posts to have no category in the URL

do you mean to NOT HAVING www.site.com/category/category-name? or not having www.site.com/category/post?

EDIT #1

To answer this:

> www.site.com/category/post is what I ONLY want for blog posts with the category of "Blog" > if the category is "Shoes" I don't want the category displayed in the URL. –

First: you can set the Permalink to `/%postname%/` so all your post will have site/title therefore accessible from that link

Second: You have to filter the permalink to behave differently for the posts under "Blog" category.

Try this

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
    foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
        $post_cat    = get_category( $cat );
        $post_cats[] = $post_cat->slug;
    }

    // Check if the post have 'blog' category
    // Assuming that your 'Blog' category slug is 'blog'
    // Change 'blog' to match yours
    if ( in_array( 'blog',$post_cats ) ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url( 'blog/' . $post->post_name ) );
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```

Third: You have to filter rewrite_rules

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_rewrite_rule' );
function custom_rewrite_rule( $rules ) {
    $new_rules = array(
        'blog/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
        'blog/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
        'blog/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]'
    );

    $rules = $new_rules + $rules;

    return $rules;
}
```

Go to permalink setting and save the setting to refresh your rewrite rules and make the changes above active

NOTE: Add those functions on your active theme `functions.php` template

NOTICE: I haven't test it yet but that's the way you change permalink. I did the similar way to change my permalink on archives and search result.

Comment: www.site.com/category/post is what I ONLY want for blog posts with the category of "Blog" if the category is "Shoes" I don't want the category displayed in the URL.

Comment: I haven't forgotten, I will try this soon and get back to you. I'm in the middle of moving, so it's a little hectic at the moment. Thanks for taking the time to reply, and I'll return the courtesy and try your code out.

Comment: This worked great for me on one category, but when I tried to add another rule it broke... but only for the 2nd one. Any ideas? The two rules are identical (besides being for different categories, of course.) Do I add a separate filter for each rule or can I keep two filters with multiple categories within?

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to recycle the permalinks. Save a new structure then save back again. Thanks for this, works great!

Comment: Any chance you'd be interested in whipping this up into a plugin?